# Node Express Trouble returning object to view from query

Tags: mongodb, model-view-controller, express

I'm trying to:

1. Pass user's ID to a model query, that should return the user record from mongo.
2. Render this user object to my view so I can use its fields.

I'm not quite sure what's going wrong - the query function finds the correct user and I can console.dir to see all the fields. When I try to return it to my view with res.render I get nothing:

Here's my route:

```
app.get('/account', function(req, res) {
  res.render('account', {title: 'Your Account', username: req.user.name, user:account.check(req.user.id)  }); 
});
```

And my query function:

```
exports.check = function(userId) { 
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
if(err) throw err;
var collection = db.collection('test'); 
collection.findOne({userId : userId}, function(err, user) {
if (err) throw err; 
console.log("account.check logging found user to console: ");
console.dir(user); 
return user;

    });
 });    
}
```

Again, this shows the proper entry

Finally my view:

```
<h1>Account Page</h1>
<hr>
<p>Why, Hello, there <b> {{username}} </b> </p><br/>

<p>You came from {{user.provider}}</p>

<p>{{user.lastConnected}}</p>

<a href="/">Go Home</a> ~ <a href="logout">Log Out</a>
```

Any held would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB findOne function is asynchronous (it takes a callback as an argument). This means that your check function also needs to be asynchronous and take a callback as an argument (or return a promise).

Then you should call res.render() inside the callback you pass to query on success.

```
app.get('/account', function(req, res) {

  account.check(req.user.id, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
      // do something smart like res.status(500).end()
      return;
    }
    res.render('account', {title: 'Your Account', username: req.user.name, user:user });  
  }

});
```

And the check function should be something like:

```
exports.check = function(userId, callback) { 
  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    if(err) {
       callback(err);
    }

    var collection = db.collection('test'); 
    collection.findOne({userId : userId}, function(err, user) {
      if(err) {
        callback(err);
      }

      console.log("account.check logging found user to console: ");
      console.dir(user); 

      callback(null, user);
    });
  });    
}
```

Of course if you don't need to do any additional processing, you can just pass your the callback argument as the callback to collection.findOne(). I just kept it this way because it was closer to what you were doing initially.